# symfony serializer type casting while deserializing

Tags: symfony, deserialization, serialization

Let's say I have a class

```
class MyObj
{
    /** @var int */
    private $myProp;

    public function getMyProp(): int
    {
        return $this->myProp;
    }

    public function setMyProp(int $myProp): self
    {
        $this->myProp = $myProp;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

If I want to deserialize following

```
$body = '{"myProp": "4"}';
$myObj = $serializer->deserialize($body, MyObj::class, 'json');
```

I obviously get an error saying that the types do not match.

> The type of the "myProp" attribute for class "MyObj" must be one of "int" ("string" given).

Can I configure the serializer to typecast those values?

Comment: `{"myProp": "4"}` ahould be `{"myProp": 4}`

Comment: It can be done via using normalizer in serializer component. You will have to write parsing logic for whatever property you want to convert, that works for complex objects too and worth learning. (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ObjectNormalizer has an option to disable type enforcement when denormalizing which you can pass via the context parameter.

```
# ... 
$myObj = $serializer->deserialize(
    $body,
    MyObj::class,
    'json',
    ['disable_type_enforcement' => true]
);
# ...
```

Since you are using a type hint in your setter, php will try to convert the given value to int.

Comment: but what if someone sent `{"myProp": "4fobar"}` then we get error instead casting to `{"myProp": 4}`, can we force casting?

Comment: @patryno I think there is no predefined PHP function or method that could handle this conversion deterministically. The Symfony Serializer is a tool, not a magician. So it can't know out of the box what you want.

You can write your own denormalizer which accepts such input. Just decorate (use Decorator Pattern) e.g. the ObjectNormalizer.